# Error #1069: Property not found on and there is no default value

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

am having an issue with a project I am working on in Flash Builder.
Following is my stack and code example. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

-- Stack --

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property page4 not found on WOAPPv2 and there is no default value.
    at WOAPPv2/dragDropHandler()[/Users/martinw/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4/WOAPPv2/src/WOAPPv2.mxml:165]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12528]
    at mx.managers.dragClasses::DragProxy/_dispatchDragEvent()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\dragClasses\DragProxy.as:374]
    at mx.managers.dragClasses::DragProxy/mouseUpHandler()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\dragClasses\DragProxy.as:599]

--Code Example -- This what works

```
import mx.core.DragSource;
import mx.events.DragEvent;
import mx.managers.DragManager;

        private function initiateDrag(event:MouseEvent,value:String):void{

            var dragInitiator:Image= event.currentTarget as Image;   

            var dragSource:DragSource = new DragSource();
            dragSource.addData(value, 'value');
            DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, dragSource, event);
        } 

        private function dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
            var dropTarget:VBox =event.currentTarget as VBox;
            if (event.dragSource.hasFormat('value')) {
                DragManager.acceptDragDrop(dropTarget);
            }
        }

private function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
            var pageName:String = event.currentTarget.name as String;
            var value:String = event.dragSource.dataForFormat('value') as String;
            this[pageName].source = "assets/big/"+value; 


        }
```

```
<s>

<s:HGroup id="hGr"
              requestedColumnCount="2"
              variableColumnWidth="false"
              columnWidth="475"
              height="450"
              gap="100"
              clipAndEnableScrolling="true" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10">


        <mx:VBox name="page1"
                 backgroundColor="#EFEFF0"
                 verticalScrollPolicy="off" 
                 horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                 horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
                 dragEnter="dragEnterHandler(event)"
                 dragDrop="dragDropHandler(event)"
                 width="475"
                 x="0">


            <mx:Image id="page1" showBusyCursor="true" width="713" height="692" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true" minWidth="713" minHeight="692" scaleX="1" scaleY="1" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top"/>
        </mx:VBox>


    </s:HGroup>
```

It Breaks If I do it this way by creating the containers and Images on runtime

```
<script>


   private function initVars():void {
            createSpreads();
        }


        public function createSpreads():void {

            var s:VBox = new VBox();
            s.name ="page4";

            s.setStyle("backgroundColor","#fe0000"); 
            s.verticalScrollPolicy="off";
            s.horizontalScrollPolicy="off";
            s.setStyle("horizontalAlign","center");
            s.setStyle("verticalAlign","middle");
            s.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_ENTER, dragEnterHandler);
            s.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_DROP, dragDropHandler);
            s.width= 475;
            s.setStyle("x","0");
            hGr.addElement(s);

            hGrCol4.text = "Vboxname: "+s.name+"VboxID: "+s.id;

            var page3:Image = new Image();
            page3.id ="page4";

            page3.showBusyCursor = true;
            page3.width = 713;
            page3.height = 692
            page3.scaleContent = true;
            page3.maintainAspectRatio = true;
            page3.minWidth = 713;
            page3.minHeight = 692;
            page3.scaleX = 1;
            page3.scaleY = 1;
            page3.source = "assets/big/IMG_7112.jpg";
            page3.setStyle("backgroundColor","#ffffff");
            page3.setStyle("horizontalAlign","center");
            page3.setStyle("verticalAlign","top");
            s.addElement(page3);

            hGrCol3.text = "Imagename: "+page3.name+"ImageID: "+page3.id;
        }


import mx.core.DragSource;
import mx.events.DragEvent;
import mx.managers.DragManager;

        private function initiateDrag(event:MouseEvent,value:String):void{

            var dragInitiator:Image= event.currentTarget as Image;   

            var dragSource:DragSource = new DragSource();
            dragSource.addData(value, 'value');
            DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, dragSource, event);
        } 

        private function dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
            var dropTarget:VBox =event.currentTarget as VBox;
            if (event.dragSource.hasFormat('value')) {
                DragManager.acceptDragDrop(dropTarget);
            }
        }

private function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
            var pageName:String = event.currentTarget.name as String;
            var value:String = event.dragSource.dataForFormat('value') as String;
            this[pageName].source = "assets/big/"+value; 

        }


</script>

<s>

<s:HGroup id="hGr"
              requestedColumnCount="2"
              variableColumnWidth="false"
              columnWidth="475"
              height="450"
              gap="100"
              clipAndEnableScrolling="true" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10">

    </s:HGroup>

</s>
```

Above with no containers in HGroup returns the 'property page4 not found on WOAPPv2 and there is no default value' - My end result should be this

page4.source = "assets/big/imagename.jpg";

I am stumped. Im rethinking it and may just create the vboxes and then set a trigger to create the image and populate in the samedragDropHandler.
Thoughts?

Below is the solution - again - thanks goes to alxx. Now I need to start contributing my knowledge to other folks on here.

```
public function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void {

        // Retrieve the Image Name from Drop
        var value:String = event.dragSource.dataForFormat('value') as String;

                    //
        event.currentTarget.getChildAt(0).source = "assets/big/"+value;

        }
```

Comment: Dude, I can't find 165-th line in your code! Where is it? By the way, FB got excellent debugger, you should use it.

Comment: OK, it must be `this[pageName]`. Your app has no property pageName (var pageName doesn't count - property will be looked by the value of pageName.)

Comment: -1.  You can't just paste all your code and expect us to debug it for you.

Comment: Apologies. This is the first time posting to Q&A board. I did my research and cannot figure it out. I will post just the code that is at fault next time. alxx - thanks for your time. I have tried creating properties based on adobe's examples. Could you please share a link or insight as to how to create a property for that? My goal was to addelement a vbox and image child that shared the name with an id and use the event to grab the currenttarget name being the image control - this[pageName] returns the correct string - page4 but bombs out. Should I put property in declarations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...continuing here for proper formatting
Problem line:

```
var value:String = event.dragSource.dataForFormat('value') as String;
this[pageName].source = "assets/big/"+value;
```

> My goal was to addelement a vbox and
>   image child that shared the name with
>   an id and use the event to grab the
>   currenttarget name being the image
>   control

Not sure if I understand it right. If event.currentTarget is Image you need, you can just cast it to Image. Or you need to find another Image somewhere (one generated in Repeater)?

**update**

> "I am trying to use the name of the VBox as a string to use for dot notation to reference the Image inside of it"

Names of DisplayObjects are only labels, not references. If you think you can traverse object hierarchy with names like in JS DOM, then no, it's done other way in Flash. You can get *reference* to VBox with `event.currentTarget` - it's more useful that its name (String). You can get Image inside it with getChildAt.

Comment: event.currentTarget.name is returning the name of the Vbox as a string and populating the pageName variable. I am trying to use the name of the VBox as a string to use for dot notation to reference the Image inside of it that has the Id of the same name. It works If I create the containers manually - but fails if I try to use AddElement on run time. I hope I am explaining it right. I will modify my code to show you when it works and when it does not. Again, thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Excellent. That makes sense now. Thank you for clearing that up. I spent about 4 hours last night reworking it and had a solution. Its not as clean as the right way. I was basically creating a new child and giving it an image source and then removing the last child. Not very practical memory wise. I have updated my code above to reflect the solution. Man... -2 ? I've been researching and coding my @$$ off - I guess coming from a background of flash MX and PHP to flex is frowned upon. Thanks alxx - +1 for you sir.

Comment: People just don't like confusing questions with a lot of code... Don't give up, they can be very helpful anyway :)